# Como imprimir somente uma venda com seus produtos usando jasperReport?

Tags: java, html, mysql, jasper-reports, jasper

Estou tentando imprimir só a venda deseja com relatórios jasperSoft, só que está imprimindo todas as vendas e todos os produtos que então adicionados em outras vendas.

**Imagem do relatório jasperSoft**
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**impressao.java**

```
        String relatorioStream = servlet.getRealPath(this.caminhoRelatorio);

        parametros.put("foto", caminhofoto);
        JasperPrint print = JasperFillManager.fillReport(relatorioStream, this.parametros, connection);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Meu Caro, como voce esta informando os dados para o relatorio ? JavaBeans ? Pesquisa direto no Banco ? como os dados estão sendo informados?. Adicione essa informação se for via SQL poste o codigo com a query.

Lendo a sua descrição se fosse via SQL eu diria que vc nao especificou a clausula Where no SQL informando o numero da venda e nao fez os devidos Joins na sua consulta com os itens da nota. Então Poste mais detalhes

Comment: Era isso mesmo, nao tava colocando a clausula where, valeu